# How to move image in Kineticjs on mousedown?

Tags: jquery, html, kineticjs

I am developing an javascript editor using Kineticjs where I can add images and move them to up, down, left and right directions. I have managed to move image to any of these directions by using move method of the group like this

```
CurrentGroup.move(0,-1);
```

Now I want that when user click on any up, down , left and right key. The image should keep moving on the mousedown as long as the user keep the mouse clicked. I am stuck here because my current method is not working in this scenario.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can listen for keydown events on the document and move your Kinetic object appropriately.**

```
$(document).keydown(function (event) {
    switch(event.which){
        case 37: // left-arrow
            CurrentGroup.move(-1,0);
            layer.draw();
            break;
        case 39: // right-arrow
            CurrentGroup.move(1,0);
            layer.draw();
            break;
        case 38: // up-arrow
            CurrentGroup.move(0,-1);
            layer.draw();
            break;
        case 40: // down-arrow
            CurrentGroup.move(0,1);
            layer.draw();
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: markE your solution is really awesome and I am marking it as accepted answer. Actually In the same way I need to move image on mousedown. When user clicks on arrow button then as long as the mouse key is down the image should keep moving. So kindly help me in this regard.

Comment: Here's an example implementing move on mousedown:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/yZDa8/  Cheers!